# Finding the number of solutions and the solutions in a given interval of a Linear Diophantine Equation

Tags: algorithm

I recently studied **Linear Diophantine Equation** and found one possible solution using **Extended Euclidean approach** but what if we are given a **range of permissible 'x' and 'y'** and asked to count the **number of solutions** and also **find the solutions**. I already looked this at [here](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/linear-diophantine-equation.html) but was not able to understand it more clearly. Any other approach or explaining the above approach in easier words is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Once you have the parametric solution, then imposing that the solutions are in the given interval gives you a range for the values of the parameter. Compute that range, and let the parameter take the integer values in that range. Finally, compute the solutions corresponding to each of those values of the parameter. If it is only counting, then just count the number of integer values in the admissible range for the parameter.

Comment: In your link, the parameter is the `k`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  If you have a *specific* point of confusion, then explain and we'll clear it up.  However, asking us to explain the entire method some other way is out of scope here.

Answer (score 0):

I have read [this](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/linear-diophantine-equation.html) in cp-algorithms. The code was unclear to me, but I have written a code, which works correctly and is easier to understand. Actually, I have checked the correctness of my code by solving [this problem](http://codeforces.com/problemsets/acmsguru/problem/99999/106) in codeforces. It is the python version of my code :

```py
from math import ceil, gcd, floor


def GCD(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        x = 1
        y = 0
        return(x, y)
    A, B = GCD(b, a % b)
    x = B
    y = A-B*(a//b)
    return(x, y)


def find_ans(a, b, c, minx, maxx, miny, maxy):
    if c % gcd(abs(a), abs(b)) != 0:
        return 0
    sb = b//abs(b)  # sign of a
    sa = a//abs(a)  # sign of b
    x, y = GCD(abs(a), abs(b))  # a solution to the equation
    x *= sa  # adjusting the sign of x
    y *= sb  # adjusting the sign of x
    g = gcd(abs(a), abs(b))
    x *= c//g
    y *= c//g
    # lk1 (left_k) = lower bound for k due to [minx , maxx]
    lk1 = (minx-x)*g/b  # x+k*b/g >= minx --> k >= (minx-x)*g/b (if b>0)
    # rk1 (right_k) = upper bound for k due to [minx , maxx]
    rk1 = (maxx-x)*g/b  # x+k*b/g <= maxx --> k <= (maxx-x)*g/b (if b>0)
    # till this line of code, we have assumed that b>0 and we have : (minx-x)*g/b <= k <= (maxx-x)*g/b
    # if b<0, then : (minx-x)*g/b >= k >= (maxx-x)*g/b . Thus the lower bound and the upper bound will change
    if sb == -1:
        lk1, rk1 = rk1, lk1
    # for example if lk1= 1.5 , we have k>=2 ( the reason is that k must be integer), so we have to use ceil for lower bound
    lk1 = ceil(lk1)
    # for example if lk1= 10.5 , we have k<=10 , so we have to use floor for upper bound
    rk1 = floor(rk1)

    # we do the same thing for a
    rk2 = (y-miny)*g/a  # y-k*a/g >= miny --> k <= (y-miny)*g/a (if a>0)
    lk2 = (y-maxy)*g/a  # y-k*a/g <= maxy --> k >= lk2 = (y-maxy)*g/a (if a>0)
    if sa == -1:
        lk2, rk2 = rk2, lk2
    lk2 = ceil(lk2)
    rk2 = floor(rk2)
    #### finding the interval ####
    lans = max(lk1, lk2)  # lower bound of interval
    rans = min(rk1, rk2)  # upper bound of interval
    # it occurs when we have ( lk1 ------ rk1   lk2 ------ rk2 ) or (lk2 ------- rk2   lk1 -------- rk1).[lk1,rk1] and [lk2,rk2] don't have intersection
    if rans < lans:
        print(0)
    else:
        print(rans-lans+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented and tested Linear Diophantine Equation in Java. The implementation is commented out to understand better. It covers the following points

- Finding One Solution
- Finding Multiple Solutions
- Finding Solutions in a range

https://github.com/love1024/Algorithms-Library-In-Java/blob/main/src/Math/LinearDiophantine.java