# Linear Diophantine Equation - Finding the number of solutions and the solutions in a given interval

Tags: c++, algorithm, equation, number-theory

I am learning Linear Diophantine Equation from [cp algorithm](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/linear-diophantine-equation.html). Overall I understood the theory. But I am facing problem in the implementation.

Help me out by providing a test case where both `shift_solution(x, y, a, b, (minx - x) / b);` and `shift_solution(x, y, a, b, sign_b);` gets executed. I have tried some equations, but in every case, after `shift_solution(x, y, a, b, (minx - x) / b);` gets executed, `x becomes equal to minx`. Basically, I need a test case which will pass execute both line.

```
shift_solution(x, y, a, b, (minx - x) / b);
    if (x < minx)
        shift_solution(x, y, a, b, sign_b);
    if (x > maxx)
        return 0;
    int lx1 = x;
```

Here is the sample code from [ref](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/linear-diophantine-equation.html):

```
void shift_solution(int & x, int & y, int a, int b, int cnt) {
    x += cnt * b;
    y -= cnt * a;
}

int find_all_solutions(int a, int b, int c, int minx, int maxx, int miny, int maxy) {
    int x, y, g;
    if (!find_any_solution(a, b, c, x, y, g))
        return 0;
    a /= g;
    b /= g;

    int sign_a = a > 0 ? +1 : -1;
    int sign_b = b > 0 ? +1 : -1;

    shift_solution(x, y, a, b, (minx - x) / b);
    if (x < minx)
        shift_solution(x, y, a, b, sign_b);
    if (x > maxx)
        return 0;
    int lx1 = x;

    shift_solution(x, y, a, b, (maxx - x) / b);
    if (x > maxx)
        shift_solution(x, y, a, b, -sign_b);
    int rx1 = x;

    shift_solution(x, y, a, b, -(miny - y) / a);
    if (y < miny)
        shift_solution(x, y, a, b, -sign_a);
    if (y > maxy)
        return 0;
    int lx2 = x;

    shift_solution(x, y, a, b, -(maxy - y) / a);
    if (y > maxy)
        shift_solution(x, y, a, b, sign_a);
    int rx2 = x;

    if (lx2 > rx2)
        swap(lx2, rx2);
    int lx = max(lx1, lx2);
    int rx = min(rx1, rx2);

    if (lx > rx)
        return 0;
    return (rx - lx) / abs(b) + 1;
}
```

Comment: Your question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58104306/finding-the-number-of-solutions-and-the-solutions-in-a-given-interval-of-a-linea).

Answer (score 0):

If x < minix then first function call iterates it to closest possible x to mini and x less then mini so that we need to add one more b here.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following values:

```
a = 1
b = 1
c = 3
minx = 0
maxx = 4
miny = 0
maxy = 4
```

It will return you 4 solutions (the correct answer).